# Adding a simple search function to ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, search

Currently the only results that show up are when you change what the query is equal to I want to change this to allow user input

I have put in the feilds i just need to help to change my ajax to accept the new code search this is a key part

my html so far

```
<html>
  <head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
window.gamer = function(data) {
          var table = '<table>';
          $.each( data.results, function( key, value ) {
          table += '<tr><tr><td><img src="' + value.image + '"/></td><td><td>' + value.name + '</td><td>' + value.resource_type + '</td></tr>';
        });
            table += '</table>';
        $('#myelement').html(table);
}

$('#search').click( function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://api.giantbomb.com/search/",
      type: "get",
        data: {api_key : "516f7cff88df5d3a5e493a40dcc8499f63e667ea", query: $('#game').val(), resources : "game", field_list : "name, resource_type, image", format : "jsonp", json_callback: "gamer"} ,
      dataType: "jsonp"
    });
});


    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Game Search</h1>
  <input id="game" type="text" /><button id="search">Search</button>
  <div id="myelement"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and a jsfiddle so u can see the problem no results are shwoing up

http://jsfiddle.net/dG7w5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly you'd want something like

```
$('#search').click( function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://api.giantbomb.com/search/",
      type: "get",
      data: {api_key : "My API key", query: $('#game').val(), resources : "game", field_list : "name, resource_type, image", format : "jsonp", json_callback : "gamer" },
      dataType: "jsonp"
    });
});
```

You could listen on the change event to auto load search results while typing. But you should then also use underscores debounce method to stop too many requests being fired.

Comment: this didnt work it returned the error Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'value'

Comment: this only fixed the error it did no help with the search the results never showed ?

Comment: Verify you get input returned with something like #search.onclick alert($('#game').val()); And check that your callback is firing with alert('gamer()'); All you're doing is replacing your hard coded query with a dynamic one. If your code worked previously either of the two answers here are a solution. You'll need to play around some more to offer more info or create a jsfiddle for more help.

Comment: I have made a jsfiddle hoping you can find the error in my code i have left in myapi key just to make it easy for u to help !! http://jsfiddle.net/Cwk6j/

Comment: Right thats a strange one. I haven't used jsonp before, but it was getting confused on the callback, couldn't find "gamer" function. I made gamer global which has fixed the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/bamboo/5yPQw/1/

Comment: it works great in the fiddle Im just having one problem i have posted your new code above but the code from the fiddle doesnt work when i try to make it into a html doc any idea WHY ??

Comment: Its a good habit to start using the console log when doing any type of JS. It'll point you in the right direction straight away, or if not paste the output to stackoverflow ;) Any way I can only assume it's trying to assign a click handler before the document has loaded, jsfiddle auto wraps JS in a ready function, try the code in this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bamboo/5yPQw/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        function btnClick() {
          $.ajax({
            url: "http://api.giantbomb.com/search/",
            type: "post",
            data: {api_key : "API KEY", query: $('#game').value, 
                   resources : "game", field_list : "name, resource_type, image", 
                   format : "jsonp" },
            dataType: "jsonp"
          })
          .done(function(gbdata, gbstatus) {
              alert( 'Done: ' + JSON.stringify(gbdata) );
          })
          .fail(function(gbstatus) {
              alert( 'Fail: ' + JSON.stringify(gbstatus) );
          })
          .always(function(gbdata, gbstatus) {
              $('#myelement').html( JSON.stringify(gbdata) );
              alert( 'Always: ' + JSON.stringify(gbdata) );
          });
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Game Search</h1>
  <input id="game" type="text" />
  <button id="search" onclick="btnClick()">Search</button>
  <div id="myelement"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I changed the button to include a click event that fires the ajax call directly. I removed the callback from the data as jQuery has a more elegant solution (the `.done()`, `.fail()`, and `.always()`).

You will have to change out the text API KEY for your actual key.

You will also have to put code in the ajax callbacks (`.done()` etc.) to process what does come back from your query provider.

In the code example you provided, the error was having quotes around the callback function name. It should have been:

```
data: {api_key : "API KEY", query: $('#game').value, 
       resources : "game", field_list : "name, resource_type, image", 
       format : "jsonp", json_callback : gamer },
```

Comment: this didnt work it returned the error Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'value'

Comment: I corrected the error you reported. Please try again.

Comment: that fixed the error but no results are coming up there is nothing in the error log

Comment: Did you change the API key to what they gave you for an API key?

Comment: yes of course i used ur code and replaced the api key but no results or errors

Comment: Have you tried making the call using another tool like Postman to see if the query is returning data? I had to change from a GET to a POST to get the data to go across. I have changed the cod sample above to match.

Comment: still no change tryed ur new code still the same emetpy results and no errors i think we might be missing something is there not ment to be some code for the button ????

Comment: Make a fiddle of your code that works except for the error. Then provide the link.

Comment: i just have one problem i dont know what to put in the .done() function ??????? currently i am looking to just bring in the title and resource and image ?

Comment: any help with the above problem ??